# How to show highlight when I click an arrow in jsPlumb library?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

Any idea how to change a particular arrow colour when the arrow has been clicked?

I am using jsPlumb and there would be something with jsPlumb.bind('click')

Answer (score 0):

Bind the connection with event:

http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#Connection.bind

Change the color of connection using function:

http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#Connection.setPaintStyle

```
Connection.bind(click,function(){
 Connection.setPaintStyle({fillStyle:'red'});
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to select a connection by the source point and end point?